# Can Throttle rate of consuming incoming messages using Akka Kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

Is there a way to read only X number of message in particular time period suppose 1 minutes using Akka kafka Stream Consumer https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/0.15/consumer.html via some configuration.
Need to handle a situation where there is bombardment  of messages from producer at particular time so consumer can be impacted.

Comment: Alpakka Kafka Streams has a built in Backpressure mechanism which prevents the overflow of your consumers, it is a much natural solution then throttling, if you want to see how it works, I wrote a blog about it https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/alpakka-kafka-stream-and-akka-finite-state-machine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `throttle` stage in Akka Streams can be used to limit the rate at which elements are passed to the next stage in a stream (using the Scala API):

```
.throttle(100, 1.minute)
```

This will still process every message in the barrage, but if there's enough time between bursts processing can catch up.

Note that Akka Streams has a robust backpressure mechanism: downstream stages will only demand enough messages that they can handle.  This in effect makes processing self-throttling: the throttle stage is useful if that's not enough or you've otherwise "opted out" of backpressure.

If there's not enough time between bursts for processing to catch up, a `buffer` stage can be put in front of the `throttle` with a drop-message-if-full strategy.  This will prevent backpressure from the throttle from propagating to the Kafka consumer, e.g.:

```
.buffer(1000, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)  // Drop the oldest message
.throttle(100, 1.minute)
```